# How to understanding the error message of elasticsearch request script?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I'm trying to debug an query script but don't know how to interpret the error message which is returned by elasticsearch. I've wrote following script for elasticsearch in python:

```
request = { "size": size,
                    "query": {
                        "script_score": {
                            "query": {
                                "match_all": {}
                            },
                            "script": {
                                "lang":"painless",
                                "source": """
                                    def m1 = doc['mask'].value;
                                    def m2 = params.queryMask;
                                    int[] x = new int[m1.length]; 
                                    for(int i; i < m1.length; i++) {
                                        if (m1.charAt(i) == '1' && m2.charAt(i) == '1') {
                                            x[i] = 1;
                                        }
                                    Debug.explain(x);
                                    def vec1 = params.queryVector * x;
                                    def vec2 = doc['gpd'] * x;
                                    return cosineSimilarity(vec1, vec2) + 1.0;
                                """,
                                "params": {
                                    "queryVector": list(featurevector),
                                    "queryMask": maskstr
                                }    
                            }
                        }
                    }
                  }
try :
    res= es.search(index=_INDEX, 
                        body=request)
except elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException as es1: 
        print(es1)
        print("---------------------------------")
        print(es1.info)
```

Which will give:

```
RequestError(400, 'search_phase_execution_exception', 'compile error')
---------------------------------
{'error': {'root_cause': [{'type': 'script_exception', 'reason': 'compile error', 'script_stack': ['...                          ', '                             ^---- HERE'], 'script': "\n                                    def m1 = doc['mask'].value;\n                                    def m2 = params.queryMask;\n                                    int[] x = new int[m1.length]; \n                                    for(int i; i < m1.length; i++) {\n                                        if (m1.charAt(i) == '1' && m2.charAt(i) == '1') {\n                                            x[i] = 1;\n                                        }\n                                    Debug.explain(x);\n                                    def vec1 = params.queryVector * x;\n                                    def vec2 = doc['gpd'] * x;\n                                    return cosineSimilarity(vec1, vec2) + 1.0;\n                                ", 'lang': 'painless', 'position': {'offset': 749, 'start': 724, 'end': 749}}], 'type': 'search_phase_execution_exception', 'reason': 'all shards failed', 'phase': 'query', 'grouped': True, 'failed_shards': [{'shard': 0, 'index': 'test2', 'node': 'glFLb94yTfSpl9drHC520A', 'reason': {'type': 'query_shard_exception', 'reason': 'failed to create query: compile error', 'index_uuid': '7SZYbCkXTGy4gtn82fmTdw', 'index': 'test2', 'caused_by': {'type': 'script_exception', 'reason': 'compile error', 'script_stack': ['...                          ', '                             ^---- HERE'], 'script': "\n                                    def m1 = doc['mask'].value;\n                                    def m2 = params.queryMask;\n                                    int[] x = new int[m1.length]; \n                                    for(int i; i < m1.length; i++) {\n                                        if (m1.charAt(i) == '1' && m2.charAt(i) == '1') {\n                                            x[i] = 1;\n                                        }\n                                    Debug.explain(x);\n                                    def vec1 = params.queryVector * x;\n                                    def vec2 = doc['gpd'] * x;\n                                    return cosineSimilarity(vec1, vec2) + 1.0;\n                                ", 'lang': 'painless', 'position': {'offset': 749, 'start': 724, 'end': 749}, 'caused_by': {'type': 'illegal_argument_exception', 'reason': 'unexpected end of script.', 'caused_by': {'type': 'no_viable_alt_exception', 'reason': None}}}}}], 'caused_by': {'type': 'script_exception', 'reason': 'compile error', 'script_stack': ['...                          ', '                             ^---- HERE'], 'script': "\n                                    def m1 = doc['mask'].value;\n                                    def m2 = params.queryMask;\n                                    int[] x = new int[m1.length]; \n                                    for(int i; i < m1.length; i++) {\n                                        if (m1.charAt(i) == '1' && m2.charAt(i) == '1') {\n                                            x[i] = 1;\n                                        }\n                                    Debug.explain(x);\n                                    def vec1 = params.queryVector * x;\n                                    def vec2 = doc['gpd'] * x;\n                                    return cosineSimilarity(vec1, vec2) + 1.0;\n                                ", 'lang': 'painless', 'position': {'offset': 749, 'start': 724, 'end': 749}, 'caused_by': {'type': 'illegal_argument_exception', 'reason': 'unexpected end of script.', 'caused_by': {'type': 'no_viable_alt_exception', 'reason': None}}}}, 'status': 400}
```

After custom pretty-printing by myself i'll get:

```
error:
         root_cause
         type:script_exception
         reason:compile error
         script_stack
                 ...                          
                                              ^---- HERE
         script:
                                    def m1 = doc['mask'].value;
                                    def m2 = params.queryMask;
                                    int[] x = new int[m1.length]; 
                                    for(int i; i < m1.length; i++) {
                                        if (m1.charAt(i) == '1' && m2.charAt(i) == '1') {
                                            x[i] = 1;
                                        }
                                    Debug.explain(x);
                                    def vec1 = params.queryVector * x;
                                    def vec2 = doc['gpd'] * x;
                                    return cosineSimilarity(vec1, vec2) + 1.0;
                                
         lang:painless
         position:
                 offset:749
                 start:724
                 end:749
         type:search_phase_execution_exception
         reason:all shards failed
         phase:query
         grouped:True
         failed_shards
         shard:0
         index:test2
         node:glFLb94yTfSpl9drHC520A
         reason:
                 type:query_shard_exception
                 reason:failed to create query: compile error
                 index_uuid:7SZYbCkXTGy4gtn82fmTdw
                 index:test2
                 caused_by:
                         type:script_exception
                         reason:compile error
                         script_stack
                                 ...                          
                                                              ^---- HERE
                         script:
                                    def m1 = doc['mask'].value;
                                    def m2 = params.queryMask;
                                    int[] x = new int[m1.length]; 
                                    for(int i; i < m1.length; i++) {
                                        if (m1.charAt(i) == '1' && m2.charAt(i) == '1') {
                                            x[i] = 1;
                                        }
                                    Debug.explain(x);
                                    def vec1 = params.queryVector * x;
                                    def vec2 = doc['gpd'] * x;
                                    return cosineSimilarity(vec1, vec2) + 1.0;
                                
                         lang:painless
                         position:
                                 offset:749
                                 start:724
                                 end:749
                         caused_by:
                                 type:illegal_argument_exception
                                 reason:unexpected end of script.
                                 caused_by:
                                         type:no_viable_alt_exception
                                         reason:None
         caused_by:
                 type:script_exception
                 reason:compile error
                 script_stack
                         ...                          
                                                      ^---- HERE
                 script:
                                    def m1 = doc['mask'].value;
                                    def m2 = params.queryMask;
                                    int[] x = new int[m1.length]; 
                                    for(int i; i < m1.length; i++) {
                                        if (m1.charAt(i) == '1' && m2.charAt(i) == '1') {
                                            x[i] = 1;
                                        }
                                    Debug.explain(x);
                                    def vec1 = params.queryVector * x;
                                    def vec2 = doc['gpd'] * x;
                                    return cosineSimilarity(vec1, vec2) + 1.0;
                                
                 lang:painless
                 position:
                         offset:749
                         start:724
                         end:749
                 caused_by:
                         type:illegal_argument_exception
                         reason:unexpected end of script.
                         caused_by:
                                 type:no_viable_alt_exception
                                 reason:None
 status:400
```

So, where/ which line does the ^---- HERE refering to? And what means 'no_viable_alt_exception'?
Besides, what does the position (offset,sart,end) arguments refering to?

Are there any better ways to debug a query script?

Greetings,
Christian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is quite cryptic but a first good start would be closing the for loop curly braces:

```
  for(int i; i < m1.length; i++) {
      if (m1.charAt(i) == '1' && m2.charAt(i) == '1') {
          x[i] = 1;
      }
  }   <--
  Debug.explain(x);
```

Generally speaking, `offset, start, end` refer to the position of the problematic character in the script payload.

Comment: Yes, the curly braces fixed the issue. So is the payload equal to the content of the script field? Because an offset of 749 seems a bit too large for the string in the script field.

Comment: JSON does not support multiline strings -- that's why it'll all be one long line with `\n`s in there.